# Is there any design pattern to use?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I should use and name a design pattern for following problem:

I have separate interfaces: `Basic`, `Complex`. All classes implement `Basic`. Some of the classes implement `Complex` but they have to inherit from Abstract class.

I was thinking about decorator but I don't know if I'm right.

[image]

Code is in Java.

Comment: Witout any practical use cases it is IMHO hard to say if it is possible ot that it makes sense. From the theoretical aspect that is possible. But you should not use a design patter because it exists you should use it when it makes sense.

Comment: With the information you've given the decorator pattern doesn't really make sense

Comment: At first glance i do not see any pattern matching. Perhaps seeing some members of the classes would help. So in this case, expecting no more info, most likely it is either no pattern or perhaps fascade.

Comment: You have an interface Complex and also a class Complex?

Comment: Not a `decorator` since it requires composition.

Comment: Yes, it's called the Classes-with-interfaces-and-common-ancestor pattern ;-)

Comment: This looks like it was drawn in Visual Paradigm, but inheritance was marked as dependency, and implementation was marked as inheritance.. o_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like **Builder** design pattern can be good for this case:
first Create an interface for the **Basic**

```
public interface Basic{ 
   public void  basicOp();
}
```

second: create an interface for the **Complex** one:

```
public interface Complex{ 
   public void complexOp();
   public Basic basicOp();
}
```

Third: create required classes which implements basic interface:(**Class2**)

```
public class abstractBasicA implements Basic { 
   @Override
   public void basicOp() { ... }
}
```

fourth: create abstract required classes for complex interface

```
public abstract class AbstractClassComplexA implements Complex{ 
   @Override 
   public complexOp() { ... } 

   @Override 
   public abstract Basic basicOp(){...}
}
```

fifth: create all other classes which extends above abstract class(**Class3, Class4, Class5**).

Comment: This is not a builder pattern. There's no product, and no builder that builds the product.

Comment: yes of course, and this is not exactly Builder design pattern, I told something a little similar to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with decorator pattern and use composition. A `Complex` should have a `Basic` member, which could manage the `Basic` part of the `Complex` type.

Below a short example.

```
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basic basic = new BasicImpl();
        basic.basicOp();
        // main.BasicImpl.op()

        Complex ca = new ConcreteComplexA(basic);
        ca.basicOp();
        ca.complexOp();
        // main.BasicImpl.op()
        // main.ConcreteComplexA.complex()

        Complex cb = new ConcreteComplexB(basic);
        cb.basicOp();
        cb.complexOp();
        // main.BasicImpl.op()
        // main.ConcreteComplexB.complex()
    }
}

interface Basic {

    void basicOp();
}

interface Complex extends Basic {

    void complexOp();
}

class BasicImpl implements Basic {

    @Override
    public void basicOp() {
        System.out.println("main.BasicImpl.basicOp()");
    }
}

abstract class AbstractComplex implements Complex {

    private final Basic basic;

    public AbstractComplex(Basic basic) {
        this.basic = basic;
    }

    @Override
    public void basicOp() {
        basic.basicOp();
    }
}

class ConcreteComplexA extends AbstractComplex {

    public ConcreteComplexA(Basic basic) {
        super(basic);
    }

    @Override
    public void complexOp() {
        System.out.println("main.ConcreteComplexA.complex()");
    }
}

class ConcreteComplexB extends AbstractComplex {

    public ConcreteComplexB(Basic basic) {
        super(basic);
    }

    @Override
    public void complexOp() {
        System.out.println("main.ConcreteComplexB.complex()");
    }
}
```

If you want clean subtypting, you have to enforce **behavioral conformance**, i.e. adhere to all the invariants of the type (and of its methods) your inheriting from, you need `Basic` to extend `Complex`, but that feels counter-intuitive very often. But only if `Complex` redefines/specializes the inherited methods.

Comment: This can not be correct answer, there is no association between basic and complex in your code

Comment: I modeled OPs text. The image he provided does not mirror his text. And since OP did not react to comments, I'll stay with this answer, till he provides more input.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is best to make use of composition instead of inheritance. So instead of relying on a lot of subclasses, pull out the behaviour in an independent structure and inject it. Design patterns that could be playing here would be strategy and dependency injection (inversion of control).

Deep class hierarchies are often a smell indicator and often you run into problems since Java doesn't support trades and you get code duplication if you need the same behavior in different classes that don't share the same ancestor.